# HTML attribute thumbnail of video tag in React JSX is not working

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

This following Video component works fine until one of the videos got hovered on. Instead of the one that got hovered, thumbnails on every video just disappear. The behavior I want to achieve here is to only hide the thumbnail of the video that got focused. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "../css/contentsection.css";

const VideoComponent = ({
    video,
    thumbnail,
    currentlyHoveredId,
    onHover,
    id,
}) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    const play = () => {
        ref.current.play();
    };

    const pause = () => {
        ref.current.pause();
    };

    const stopVideo = () => {
        ref.current.currentTime = 0;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (currentlyHoveredId === id) {
            play(); // when focused then loop
        } else {
            pause();
            stopVideo(); // when not focused then pause loop
        }
    }, [currentlyHoveredId]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="videos">
                <video
                    className="video"
                    ref={ref}
                    autoPlay
                    onMouseOver={() => onHover(id)}
                    muted={true}
                    src={video}
                    poster={
                        currentlyHoveredId === id ? null : thumbnail
                    }
                ></video>
           </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default VideoComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over a video, you are setting the poster to null. I am assuming this is somehow causing the thumbnails to disappear for all videos. But you need only change the poster for the currently hovered video. It could be because of the way you are updating the currentlyHoveredId prop in your parent component or how you are handling hover events. Hard to tell without actually inspecting all of the code.
You can try a simpler approach and keep track of the hover state for each video component using local state. You can remove the currentlyHoveredId prop from VideoComponent. Instead, you can handle the hover state within the component itself. May be try something like this,

```js
const VideoComponent = ({ video, thumbnail, id }) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

    const play = () => {
        ref.current.play();
    };

    const pause = () => {
        ref.current.pause();
    };

    const stopVideo = () => {
        ref.current.currentTime = 0;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isHovered) {
            play(); // when focused then play
        } else {
            pause();
            stopVideo(); // when not focused then pause
        }
    }, [isHovered]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="videos">
                <video
                    className="video"
                    ref={ref}
                    autoPlay
                    onMouseOver={() => setIsHovered(true)}
                    onMouseOut={() => setIsHovered(false)}
                    muted={true}
                    src={video}
                    poster={isHovered ? null : thumbnail}
                ></video>
           </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: The reason I have currentlyHoveredId is because I want to keep the video playing until the pointer has hovered over another video. So, I have a useState(id: number) in the parent container component. Maybe this can be the reason of the bug?

Comment: I combined the local state (as per your suggestion) and the global state (currentlyHoveredId) to control the playback behavior. Now, the playback depends on the local state but another useEffect will be triggered every time the global id changes to update the local state. This works. Any explanation why?

Comment: To be completely honest I have no idea! as I have said, I can't make head or tail without actually looking at all the code. But hey, you made it work!